# what's the SOTA for medical imagery classification for diagnostic purposes?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, image-classification

Many medical image datasets - Ultrasound for example - have a time component that is quite powerful. But some of the [papers](https://journals.lww.com/md-journal/FullText/2019/04120/Ultrasound_image_analysis_using_deep_learning.41.aspx) I have read use ConvNets and seem to ignore temporality.

Have there been any advances in using LSTMs and/or 3D ConvNets for medical imagery classification to leverage temporality? Can anyone shed some light on recent developments?

[2] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5116541/